# Which option is better Programming Practice

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I am writing a process that creates an extension of the Hammock REstRequest object, and wanted to know which implementation (which is very similar) would be considered the better programming practice. Here is the object definition, which has 2 constructors

```
public class RequestObject : RestRequest
{    
    public RequestObject()
    {
        this.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    }

    public RequestObject(WebMethod webMethod, byte[] ContentArray)
        : this()
    {
        if (webMethod == Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Put
            || webMethod == Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Post)
        {
            //encode payload string to a utf8 byte array
            this.AddPostContent(ContentArray);
            this.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }
    }
}
```

For the construction of the object, there are 2 ways I can do it, instantiate it inline, as follows:

```
string payload = serializer.Serialize(user);

RequestObject request
    = new RequestObject(WebMethod.Put, BuildAPI.GetBytes(payload))
      {
          Credentials = new BasicAuthCredentials
          {
              Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
              Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]
          },
          UserAgent = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserAgent"],
      };
```

Or call a member of a "Build Class" to construct the object:

```
public static RequestObject BuildRequest(WebMethod method, byte[] byteArray)
{
    RequestObject request = new RequestObject(WebMethod.Put, byteArray)
    {
        Credentials = new BasicAuthCredentials
        {
            Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
            Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]
        },
        UserAgent = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserAgent"],
        Method = method
    };

    return request;
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
RequestObject request = BuildAPI.BuildRequest(WebMethod.Put, payload);
```

I am just wondering which of the two options is considered better programming practices. I am reading into SOLID and now I am nervous about multiple "functions" being in the same class, but don't want to over think things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting way before the SOLID principles, you're code is very incoherent. You have some static `BuildAPI` - so either decide on sticking to it or don't use it. Because it's static, this decision should be based on whether you suspect that in the future these constructions will need to be polymorphic, or not.

Second note: do you really need two constructors? Seems like only one is used.

Third note: You initialize some of the properties in constructor, and some with the property initializer - why not just stick to one paradigm (POD object, or a class)?

Finally, as for the SOLID principles - your `RequestObject` clearly violates the Single Responsibility Principle which is evident from the fact, that you pass an `enum` to the constructor. So this class represents in fact few classes which are fit together. Consider making `RequestObject` abstract, and implement a separate sub-class for each request type.

Something like this:

```
abstract class RequestObject
{
    //properties and methods common to all requests

    protected RequestObject(...)
    {
        //initialize common properties
    }
}

class GetRequest : RequestObject
{
    public GetRequest()
    {
        this.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    }

    //... other specific things for GET
}

class PutRequest : RequestObject
{
    public PutRequest()
    {
        this.AddPostContent(ContentArray);
        this.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

    //... specific things for PUT
}
```

... you get the picture. Probably you could make also another level between `RequestObject` and `Post`, `Put` as they also probably share some behaviour.

Comment: Thanks BartoszKP, here are my responses to your notes
1. The whole static BuildAPI was one of the questions, and if adding it was not needed. So inline is a fine option then?
2. I have 2 instances when I create this object, one when I am creating a GET Request, and other when I am creating a PUT Request. The 2nd constructor is for the PUT Request because I need to add the content to the header.
3. My thought on initializing some in the constructor and not is that some properties are dependent on what constructor is being called.
4. Can you help me a little with this, I am not following.

Comment: Ad2) This is also something that violates the SRP. I've added a simple example.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful, one more question, for properties of my RequestObject class (like UserName, Password), what is the best way to initialize them, since the PUT process needs a constructor with a param. Is it ok to have have a property initializer that calls a constructor as well?

Comment: Not sure about this one, but I never do it this way. Either I have a POD, which is "stupid" so others manage its properties from the outside - that's when I use an initializer, or a class that's capable of managing itself - then only this class can initialize its properties using a constructor.

Comment: So I could theoretically place the the code that initializes my properties in the setter methods of the abstract class then?

Comment: Initialization typically is done in the constructor - so why not the base class's constructor?